# Spring Security password fails verification

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I was following Spring Security articles:
[Spring Security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter]: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter
[Spring Security Blog]: http://staging5.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter

and I keep getting the error:
*o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value*

Below is my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, 
jsr250Enabled=true)

public class WebSecurityConfig {
private static final String ROLE_ADMIN_USER = "ADMIN_USER";
private static final String ROLE_POWER_USER = "POWER_USER";
private static final String ROLE_GUEST_USER = "GUEST_USER";

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
    UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1abc"))
            .roles(ROLE_ADMIN_USER).build();
    UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2abc"))
            .roles(ROLE_POWER_USER).build();
    UserDetails user3 = User.withUsername("user3")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user3abc"))
            .roles(ROLE_GUEST_USER).build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, user3);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index").hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN_USER, ROLE_POWER_USER, ROLE_GUEST_USER)
            .antMatchers("/inventory").hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN_USER, ROLE_POWER_USER)
            .antMatchers("/guest").hasAnyRole(ROLE_GUEST_USER)
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/doLogin").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    System.out.println("--- Login successful ---");
                }
            })
            .failureUrl("/login");

    return http.build();
}
```